# Jquery File Validation with Dynamically Created File input Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I want to Validate File input field like **size** and **extension**.

I am appending more file input field based on the client requirment. See the screenshot

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7DnAEDiJntwY0pkeXlya0xPdzg/view?usp=sharing

When I use the below function to check the file name and size. but it not working on dynamically created elements.

```
 <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-Choose btn-file">
   <span class="fileinput-new">Browse File</span>
   <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
   <input class="fileimgval" type="file" name="brchrimg[]">
 </span>

 $(document).on('change','input:file',function(){
    var fileName = $(this).val();
    alert(fileName);
  });
```

When User click on the **Plus** button a new upload field in generating and manipulating with that.

How can I get the filename and size in jquery ?

Thanks

Comment: Refer this: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/03/how-to-check-file-size-before-uploading.html

Comment: its working perfectly on static html elements... but I want to get the size of the file of dynamically appended file inputs.

Comment: On which event ? As you have used event delegation, it should not be the issue..

Comment: same. on the file change event I want to get the details of file such as size and extension.. the event is not working on dynamic fields now....

Comment: I don't usually recommend plugins, but this one is worth a look: http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php.  Since trying it out, I now use it on all my projects.

Answer (score 0):

> HTML 5 File API specification, some properties of files are accessible at client side and file size is one of them. So the idea is to use the size property and find out the file size. But as it is a part of HTML 5 specification so it will only work for modern browsers. [[Ref]](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/03/how-to-check-file-size-before-uploading.html)

Try this:

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input:file', function() {
  var fileName = $(this).val();
  var iSize = $(this)[0].files[0].size / 1024;
  var size = '';
  if (iSize / 1024 > 1) {
    if (((iSize / 1024) / 1024) > 1) {
      iSize = (Math.round(((iSize / 1024) / 1024) * 100) / 100);
      size = iSize + "Gb";
    } else {
      iSize = (Math.round((iSize / 1024) * 100) / 100);
      size = iSize + "Mb";
    }
  } else {
    iSize = (Math.round(iSize * 100) / 100);
    size = iSize + "kb";
  }
  alert('fileName: ' + fileName + '  size: ' + size);
});
$('#addMore').on('click', function() {
  var html = '<br><span class="input-group-addon btn btn-Choose btn-file">\
   <span class="fileinput-new">Browse File</span>\
<span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>\
<input class="fileimgval" type="file" name="brchrimg[]">\
</span>';
  $('#parent').append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
  <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-Choose btn-file">
   <span class="fileinput-new">Browse File</span>
  <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
  <input class="fileimgval" type="file" name="brchrimg[]">
  </span>
</div>
<Button id='addMore'>Add More</Button>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/dpdkzshd/)

Comment: dude, THe event is not firing on this function. :(

Comment: There is a button-> _Run code snippet_ Click on that and let me know whether provided code is working or not ? At my end it is working as it is suppose to. You cal also go through the provided Fiddle..

Comment: its worked on he fiddle and stack answer. but not in my code. why ?

Comment: is there any issues with jquery version.. I am using 1.11.1

Comment: If it is working in provided example then there __must__ be something missing in your code. Can you provide a fiddle to make us understand the issue..