# How to get Dynamic File Input Field Value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I am developing a web application that does multiple file uploading.

When the user clicks on the plus button I am appending a new input field.

The user then selects an image from a file. I want to validate that image and if any errors are found then it needs to show the message and stop the form action.

But now the change event isn't working with my code.

Here is my code..

**HTML**

```
 <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-Choose btn-file">
  <span class="fileinput-new">Browse File</span>
  <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
  <input class="fileimgval" type="file" name="brchrimg[]">
 </span>
```

**Dynamic HTML** (same as Above)

```
<span class="input-group-addon btn btn-Choose btn-file">
  <span class="fileinput-new">Browse File</span>
  <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
  <input class="fileimgval" type="file" name="brchrimg[]">
 </span>
```

**Script to get file Info...**

```
$(document).on('change','.fileimgval',function(){
      alert($(this).val());
 });
```

There is no event firing on the static HTML file input and Dynamic Input Field.

I am Using Jquery 1.11.1

```
 <script src="../assets/global/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

What is the error ?

There is no error message in the console...

[image]

Comment: is change event fire for static html?

Comment: @OP, I have already answer [_this question_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584659/jquery-file-validation-with-dynamically-created-file-input-fields/34584848#34584848) posted by __YOU__ yesterday. And provided solution works as expected. So there is no point pushing another question..

Comment: @debin, you mean I need to add the ID attribute in dynamically maked file input right ?

Comment: Event must be registered after the DOM element is created.

Comment: Do simple `$(document).delegate(':file', 'change', function() {
   alert(this);
});`

Comment: @debin, Why do we need this ? We do not need `id` selectors here..

Comment: @RayonDabre if there are multiple file an OP wants to work on only single file change then id will help

Comment: @debin, Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/dpdkzshd/

Comment: Have you placed your JavaScript before closing `body` tag(`</body>`) ? Or use `$(document).ready(function(){ })`

Comment: it looks fine with no issues at all, have you really test it ?

Comment: @RayonDabre, Its working on your fiddle. but not in my code. What is this /

Comment: An Important Matter I am using an admin template. the file input UI updated in question. please check.

Answer (score -2):

Use this instead, It will trigger when you click the file upload

`$(document).on('click','.fileimgval',function(){
      alert($(this).val());
 });`

But It will just trigger when you click the file upload button there will be no way to validate the image. You should use this plugin instead to get this done in a cleaner way else you would mess up the whole stuff.

https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

It's simple and have a good UI.

Comment: OP is not asking for validating image

Comment: No. On change will not work here. It works for dropdown.

Comment: @Adeel, Are you kidding us ? __On change will not work here__ ?